# How to pipe numbers in to its own line

Tags: bash

I'm new to programming in general and my teacher is starting me out with simple bash scripts.

I want to know what program I can use to pipe numbers in to its own line.  I'm not sure where to start, but my teacher want me to find alternate ways to find answers.

```
echo 12345 |
```

For example:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
echo -n 12345 | sed -e 's/./&\n/g'
```

See: `help echo` and `man sed`

Answer (score 0):

A commonly used command is `seq`:

```
seq 1 5
```

Read more about it in its manpage with `man seq`.

Note: There is no pipe involved when using `seq` and you just want to get the numbers, so if a pipe has to be part of your solution, use one of the other answers.

Comment: I know what seq does but I needed to use the pipe.